# Get last activity time on a Remote Machine

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, pinvoke, powershell-remoting

I need to get the time since the keyboard mouse was last active -- but on a remote machine. -- It needs to work for any user, even if they're connected by remote desktop.

I've been able to get this information on the local machine (or even an RDP session) by P/Invoking `GetLastInputInfo` from User32.dll in both a C# console app, and in a PowerShell script.

However, the same code via remote PowerShell (or via a background service) gives me wrong information (it basically just gives me the machine uptime, as if no input events have ever been processed).

How can I get the correct time of last keyboard/mouse activity from a Remote machine? (i.e. from code that runs in a remote PowerShell context, or in a Windows service context).

Perhaps there is some setting I can change to give background processes access to the current logged in user sessions? -- Or a registry setting I can change? -- Or perhaps there's a way to enumerate the active sessions and pass in a session object to some kind of `GetLastInputInfoEx` function or something? -- How can I move forward with this?

My current PowerShell script looks like this (the C# version I'm using should be apparent as well):

```bsh
$signature = @'
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInputInfo plii);

public struct LastInputInfo
{
    public uint Size;

    public uint Time;
}

public static TimeSpan? GetIdleTime()
{
    LastInputInfo lastInput = new LastInputInfo();
    lastInput.Size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInput);

    uint envTicks = (uint)Environment.TickCount;
    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInput))
    {
        double ms = envTicks - lastInput.Time;
        if (ms >= 0)
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
'@

$type = Add-Type -Name "User32Utils" -Namespace "InteropHelpers" -MemberDefinition $signature -PassThru

return [InteropHelpers.User32Utils]::GetIdleTime();
```

Comment: Look in to [`wtsapi32.dll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383459(v=vs.85).aspx), or a wrapper library like [cassia](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cassia/).

Comment: If your code is running in session 1, can you get the info from session 2 on the same machine? How about if you're running in session 0?

Comment: Given a system service running as local system, you can duplicate your token, use `SetTokenInformation` to change the session, and `CreateProcessAsUser` to run code in the context of the target session.  `WTSEnumerateSessions` can list the sessions, I think you'll need to check all of them.  Not entirely sure it will work as desired even so.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948133/get-last-activity-time-on-a-remote-machine#comment74930232_43948133) by [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain), I was able to figure out a solution using [Cassia](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cassia/) (which I consumed via their [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cassia)).

**Disclaimer:** Please observe that this only works for RDP sessions.  (When I tested Cassia, it was not able to return the `IdleTime` or `LastInputTime` data for non-RDP sessions.  YMMV, but it works for me, since I'm writing code to monitor VMs that can only be accessed via RDP).

Additionally, while not strictly necessary, I chose to make things easier for myself by writing a quick PowerShell Cmdlet to expose the data provided by Cassia (it's `Class Library` named "CassiaCmdlet.dll" with a single class in it):

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using Cassia;

namespace CassiaCmdlet
{
    [Cmdlet("Get", "TsSession")]
    public class GetTsSession : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [Alias("ServerName", "MachineName", "Name")]
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Processes the record.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            using (var server = GetServer())
            {
                server.Open();
                foreach (var session in server.GetSessions())
                {
                    WriteObject(session);
                }
                server.Close();
            }
        }

        private ITerminalServer GetServer()
        {
            var mgr = new TerminalServicesManager();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ComputerName))
            { 
                // Local Machine
                return mgr.GetLocalServer(); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Remote Machine
                return mgr.GetRemoteServer(ComputerName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from PowerShell:

```
[Fubar]: PS C:\Scripts\Cmdlets> Import-Module .\CassiaCmdlet.dll
[Fubar]: PS C:\Scripts\Cmdlets> Get-TsSession

<... snip ...>

ClientDisplay     : Cassia.Impl.ClientDisplay
ClientBuildNumber : 0
Server            : Cassia.Impl.TerminalServer
ClientIPAddress   : 
WindowStationName : 
DomainName        : Fubar
UserAccount       : Fubar\Spock
ClientName        : 
ConnectionState   : Disconnected
ConnectTime       : 5/15/2017 11:03:07 PM
CurrentTime       : 5/15/2017 11:25:51 PM
DisconnectTime    : 5/15/2017 11:04:56 PM
LastInputTime     : 5/15/2017 11:04:56 PM
LoginTime         : 5/15/2017 10:44:34 PM
IdleTime          : 00:20:54.7733923
SessionId         : 2
UserName          : Spock

<... snip ...>
```

Of note, the dates in the session objects are in **local time** for the **remote** PowerShell system.  So you may want to convert them to Universal Time before consuming them.

Also of note, Connected sessions will have a `WindowStationName` like "RDP*", but that same session, once disconnected, will have an empty name (it still has the `LastInputTime` though!).

A simple example of using it is here:

```
# Get latest LastInputTime from a session with 
# a name like "RDP*" or that has an empty name:

$d = (Get-TsSession | Where { $_.WindowStationName -like "RDP*" -or $_.WindowStationName -eq "" } | % { $_.LastInputTime } | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum;

# Convert to Universal Time
if ($d -ne $null) { $d = $d.ToUniversalTime(); }

# Display the found input time.
$d;
```

This filters by "RDP*" or ""; Ideally you would just filter out your PowerShell session though. (I think the default name is "Console", but you could name it anything you want if you're connecting from C#, so I kept the code simple.)